# Why does "x[x.length - 1]" throw "Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid or unexpected token" on an array in the Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, chromium

Edit: a - lookalike character was the culprit.

I have a script I'm pasting into Edge's developer console that breaks with this:

```
let args;
if (typeof arguments === 'undefined') {
  args = [1, 'January', 2023, 'test', x => console.log(x)];
} else {
  args = arguments;
}
let returnCallback = args[args.length - 1];
```

The last line is what triggers "Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid or unexpected token".

I can replace `args.length - 1` with `4`, and the code runs how I expect it to.
I can even replace `args.length - 1` with `args.length`, and no errors are thrown.
I tried pasting all but the last line in, then pressing enter. I confirmed `args` is defined. Pasting that last line in still throws the error.

This is the minimum code I can reduce it to and still throw the error*:

```
let x = [1, 2];
x.length - 1;
```

The following does not throw the error:

```
let x = [1, 2];
x.length;
```

When I enter the lines individually, it gets tricky.
First, I will enter `let x = [1, 2];` and press enter.
If I paste `x.length - 1;` in and hit enter, I get the error. But if I type `x.length - 1;`, it will not give the error.
(If I set x to a single-element array, it will still error when pasting the 2 lines together. But pasting them individually always works. It needs 2+ elements for pasting vs typing to matter.)

I don't think it is just chrome cashing `x.length` when it previews the value as you type it.
For example, look at the result of these 3 lines, all pasted:
`let x = [1, 2];` *enter*
Result: undefined
`x.length` *enter*
Result: 2
`x.length - 1` *enter*
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or expected token

The error it gives isn't what you'd expect in that scenario either.
If I run `x.length - 1` without declaring x, the output is "Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined"
If I run it after `let x;`, the output is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"
If I set x to something without a length property, the result is `NaN`

So it's more than the console having an incorrect or no value for the variable.

Is this a problem with my code? Or am I running into a bug on Edge?

Comment: `typeof argments === 'undefined'`

Comment: I have a feeling you need to give us more code/context here.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I just fixed that in the question. I double checked my code, and that type wasn't there. (I'm on a work laptop that doesn't allow pasting on stack overflow and had to type that out.)

Comment: There are a few tools to inspect strings. E.g., when doing `"x.length - 1".length`, I expect `12`. When doing `Array.from("x.length - 1")`, I expect `[ "x", ".", "l", "e", "n", "g", "t", "h", " ", "-", " ", "1" ]`. When doing `Array.from("x.length - 1", (string) => string.codePointAt())`, I expect `[ 120, 46, 108, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 45, 32, 49 ]`. When doing `Array.from("x.length - 1", (string) => string.codePointAt().toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0")).join(" ")`, I expect `"78 2E 6C 65 6E 67 74 68 20 2D 20 31"`. [Edit] your post and provide a [mre] we can work with.

Comment: Make sure the `-` is the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, and not e.g. `−` (U+2212 MINUS SIGN) or something else.

Comment: How is [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) not in a function? unclear how it would be set.

Comment: And for the context, that's the start of my script. There isn't any code above it. I'm using Selenium to inject the code into a page. Selenium runs the code you write as a function with arguments you passed it from the api. And the last argument is a callback to give the result in async calls. The `if (typeof arguments === 'undefined')` block is so I can paste the code into the console to test it.

Comment: Can you test those code on other browser/device? I can run them with no issue.

Comment: And you verified it is an array.... `console.log(typeof arguments, Array.isArray(arguments), arguments);`

Comment: @SebastianSimon that was it, lol. It all makes sense now!

Comment: `If I paste x.length - 1; in and hit enter, I get the error. But if I type x.length - 1;, it will not give the error.`
...
`I'm on a work laptop that doesn't allow pasting on stack overflow`
...
Makes me wonder if when you paste, a restriction applied by your employer means you aren't pasting what you think you're pasting.

Comment: using a tool like a linter on your IDE would have pointed out your error. Put your code in https://eslint.org/play/ and it would put an error on that character.

Comment: @MikeK, that could be it.  
I wrote the code in Jetbrains IDEA and pasted it to the dev console. It would be weird for one of those programs to edit text like that. So I suspect the windows clipboard or some other process on my computer did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong "-" sign. I was using "−" (U-2212 "Minus Sign")
Thanks to Sebastian Simon for suggesting I check for this.